# iphone with some information in general

Tags: iphone

what is meaning of (iPhone SDK) iOS 4.2 in as a software requirement.
please reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means probably that your application has to run on devices with iOS 4.2 and higher.
You can set this in 'Deployment target' setting of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Software Development Kit which will be having iOS4.2 as its base sdk. 
in short XCode 3.2.5